# Keeping selected value in dropdown list after refreshing page

Tags: php, html, select

Hello im trying to keep the chosen value in my dropdown list after refreshing the page.

This is my code.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="location[]" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
        <option name="500" <?php echo ($_POST['location'] == '500') ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?> value="500">DE (19% MwSt)</option>
        <option name="100" <?php echo ($_POST['location'] == '100') ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?> value="100">IT (22% MwSt)</option>
        <option name="1500" <?php echo ($_POST['location'] == '1500') ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?> value="1500">CH (0% MwSt)</option>
    </select>
    <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
</form>
```

But this doesnt work. 
If i remove the `[]` in the select name the chosen value is saved after refreshing the page, but the form doesnt work anymore.
If i add the `[]` to the `$_POST['location']` then the chosen value is not saved after refreshing. 
Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but a alternate approach.

What if you use AJAX for submitting your form. You wouldn't need to refresh your page on submitting (assuming this is your problem), This way you dont need to refresh your page.

I recommend using jquery for this. I could provide you with an example if you need one.

In order to make a submit your data using ajax you need to include Jquery in your html. [Jquery](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery)

Now you can do something like this.

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
//When element with id=submit is clicked execute this code
    $.ajax({
        Type:"POST",
        url: "yourphpfile.php",
        //at data: You can add your own strings
        data: {Data: "The data you want to send"},
        success: function(){
            //this gets executed when ajax succeeds
            alert("great succes");
        }
    });
});
```

You can acces the data in PHP using $_POST

```
$String = $_POST['Data'];
```

In this case it would be: "The data you want to send".

I hope this gets you started.

Comment: Im not really good into this stuff at all. How would that work? Do you have any code for that example?

Comment: I assume that you want to send the data to a php file?

Comment: no i just want to give a information on the current site. the form is working, just the variable is not kept in the dropdown. it keeps jumping back to the first one after refreshing.

Comment: If you just want to load the current preferences you should load it from a database, or use some sort of local storage like cookies.

Comment: no this is not helping me. i just want that the selected value is saved in the session and that the selected value + the result will not be reloaded on page refresh. 
The best thing would be that the complete div is saved in the session where the form and the result is located.